# passing numeric where parameter condition in postgress using python

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use postgresql in Python.The query is against a numeric field value in the where condition. The result set is not fetching and giving error ("psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch").There are records in the database with agent_id (integer field) > 1.

```
import psycopg2
# Try to connect
try:
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' host ='localhost')
except:
  print "Error connect to the database."

cur = conn.cursor()
agentid = 10000

try:
    sql = 'SELECT * from agent where agent_id > %s::integer;'
    data = agentid
    cur.execute(sql,data)
except: 
     print "Select error"

rows = cur.fetchall()
print "\nRows: \n"`
for row in rows:``
    print "   ", row[9]
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your error message, but i think the syntax is off. Why not try casting your agentid as int with python then dynamically generating your sql and passing to cur.execute() function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try these things in your code:

```
conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres host=localhost user=user_here password=password_here port=port_num_here")
```

`sql = 'SELECT * from agent where agent_id > %s;`'

```
data = (agentid,)  # A single element tuple.
```

then use

```
cur.execute(sql,data)
```

Also, I am confused here to what you want to do with this code

```
for row in rows:``
    print "   ", row[9]
```

Do you want to print each row in `rows` or just the 8th index of `rows`, from

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

If you wanted that index, you could

```
print rows[9]
```